# Transforming a directory into an SVN repository

Tags: svn

There is a directory (call it A/) with many files, both source and binary.

There is an another directory (call it B/) such that A/ contains all files from B/ but in A/ there are many (binary) files not present in B/.

I create a new SVN repository from the content of B (`svn import`).

Now I need to make A/ also an SVN repository in order to be able to pull new versions. Transforming A/ into a repository we must not delete the binary files (mentioned above).

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found, it can be done with the following command:

`svn --force ...`